# React/Typescript How to set properties in inherited class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following base class which is used for the inheritance. For simplicitly there are only two properties.

```
export interface BaseClassProps{
    props1: string;
    props2?: string;
}

export interface BaseClassState{
    mode?: "loading" | 'edit';
}

export abstract class BaseClass extends React.Component<BaseClassProps, BaseClassState>{ 

   constructor(props: BaseClassProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = ({
            mode: 'loading'
        });
 }
```

I want to extend that class and fill out the properties

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass{ 

   constructor(props: BaseClassProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
   }
 }
```

Now where do I set the properties `props1` and `props2` in the extending class? Because I am getting the error that the props are not set, but I have no idea where to place them...

Comment: What if you set it like you did for the `BaseClass`? i.e. `class ChildClass extends BaseClass<BaseClassProps> { }` ?

Comment: [The React devs recommend against using inheritance with components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) - you should be using [higher order components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) instead. *"At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven't found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies."*

Comment: @Aron Doesn't work because it's not generic.

Comment: @JoeClay This is more like a View and not a Component. That's why I want to use inheritance.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, that's fine - expect to run into problems, though. It's really not how React is designed to be used.